# why use "is" instead of "are" after a plural subject?

Tags: grammatical-number

On this page : [NYPD Officer Peter Liang found guilty of manslaughter in stairwell shooting that killed Akai Gurley](https://abc7ny.com/news/nypd-officer-peter-liang-found-guilty-of-manslaughter-in-stairwell-shooting-that-killed-akai-gurley/1196360/), around 3rd screen in the middle, we have this sentence

> Meanwhile, supporters of Liang, who is Chinese-American, have said he
>   has been made a scapegoat for past injustices.

"supporterS" vs "who IS" vs "HAVE said"?

What I guess is here considers "supporters" as a whole, like "a people" means a certain group of people, am I right?

Even if yes, I still think this is too subtle for me, would you please give me another example so that I can will have an idea when to use this kind of structure?

Also, how will the meaning change if I replace "is" with "are"?

Comment: "who is Chinese-American" complements *Liang*, not *supporters*; hence the singular inflection. The subject of "have said" is *supporters*, hence the plural inflection. If you replaced "is" with "are", "who are Chinese-American" would complement *supporters*.

Comment: oh... yes, I overlooked it. Just a follow-up question I think suitable to ask here: If I do want to modify the "supporters", in this situation, how should I place the clause?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood which part of the sentence went with who.

> supporters of **Liang, who is Chinese-American,**

The "who is" is agreeing with "Liang", who is a single person, and not with the "supporters".

I'd admit that the sentence is a bit ambiguous.

For the best clarity, the description of Liang or the supporters as Chinese Americans should be moved to a different sentence entirely.

> Liang, who is Chinese-American,

and then continue on.

Also, to get a little off track, mentioning the race of a person when it is not relevant invokes a bit of a racist mood and point of view.